# How do you get a 3 union query to ignore the first query if the first query run doesn't suit the parameters

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table containing 3 sets of dates, and 3 categories next to the dates that I wish to filter through to find dates within the last month and a specific word in the category.
If I run my union query and the first query returns with the 1st date being out of the parameter I want it to run the second query within the union query sequence to check the 2nd date column. How can I code this in in my sql View. Currently I have this coded as below.

```
SELECT table1. I'd
      ,table1.[Date Of Offence]
      ,table. [Offence Category]
      ,table1.[Offence Description]
      ,table1.[Action Taken]
FROM table1
WHERE table1.[Date Of Offence] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
AND table1.[Offence Category] = "Speeding"
OR table1.[Date Of Offence] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
AND (table1.[Offence Category] = "Speeding" IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT table1.ID
      ,table1[Date Of Offence 2]
      ,table1.[Offence Category 2]
      ,table1.[Offence Description 2]
      ,table1.[Action Taken 2]
FROM table1
WHERE table1.[Date Of Offence]) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
AND table1.[Offence Category] = "Speeding"
OR table1.[Date Of Offence] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0))
AND table1.[Offence Category]) = "Speeding" IS NULL

UNION

Into the 3rd query
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: So date 1 - 01 sep 19, date 2 01 Aug 19 within table, but I want it to ignore the first date and pull the detail for the 2nd date. It currently will find dates in the previous Callander month but if the first date column is outside this then it pulls nothing. And I want it to show me date 2

Comment: If you changed the coding above, it still doesn't work as it only shows records with a date matching the parameter of 01 Aug 19 and 30 Aug 19. If all the dates within the record are between the dates

Comment: MySQL and access are 2 different DBs. From syntax it seems MS Access. Please remove unnecessary tags.

Comment: Thabks for your help, I thought they were the same programs

Comment: There is no certain way to control the queries in Union clause. They all will return the result. However you can then limit the rows whether you need the rows from table 1 or table 2.

Comment: What should be your expected result?

Comment: My expected result is it will filter through the 3 date columns and pull the attached "speeding" in the offence column. If the date in date field 1 is outside the  parameter of the last month I want it to check date 2 field and pull the information from that point, if date 2 is out then pull date 3 and data. If all fields are outside the parameter I want it to return nothing

Comment: If any record found in Table 1, Do you need to return only that or you need record from all tables if it found in the parameter?

Comment: Technically, @AnkitBajpai, [MS Access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/ms-access-or-mdb-or-access-database-engine-or-ms-jet-ace) is both a frontend GUI application and backend SQL engine. The frontend *can* connect to MySQL and any other RDBMS either using linked tables or pass-through queries. If linked tables, queries to external sources use Access SQL. If pass-through, queries use connecting database' SQL dialect. We ask OPs to be clear on setup but here OP confused the two.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this -

```
SELECT TOP 1 table1. Id
            ,table1.[Date Of Offence]
            ,table1. [Offence Category]
            ,table1.[Offence Description]
            ,table1.[Action Taken]
FROM table1
WHERE table1.[Date Of Offence] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
AND table1.[Offence Category] = "Speeding"
OR table1.[Date Of Offence] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
AND (table1.[Offence Category] = "Speeding" IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT table1.ID
      ,table1[Date Of Offence 2]
      ,table1.[Offence Category 2]
      ,table1.[Offence Description 2]
      ,table1.[Action Taken 2]
FROM table1
WHERE table1.[Date Of Offence]) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
AND table1.[Offence Category] = "Speeding"
OR table1.[Date Of Offence] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0))
AND table1.[Offence Category]) = "Speeding" IS NULL
ORDER BY table1.[Date Of Offence]
```

Answer (score 0):

So ive rewritten the queries and all seems to work fine now. Literally used the same coding again

Answer (score 0):

Since data sources are essentially the same, consider no `UNION` but using conditional logic in the `SELECT` clause with [`IIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3). Also, parentheses are added to `OR` conditions among other syntax cleanup:

```
SELECT table1.ID
      , IIF(table1.[Date Of Offence] IS NOT NULL, table1.[Date Of Offence], table1.[Date Of Offence 2]) AS Date_of_Offence,
      , IIF(table1.[Offence Category] IS NOT NULL, table1.[Offence Category], table1.[Offence Category 2]) AS Offence_Category,
      , IIF(table1.[Offence Description] IS NOT NULL, table1.[Offence Description], table1.[Offence Description 2]) AS Offence_Description,
      , IIF(table1.[Action Taken] IS NOT NULL, table1.[Action Taken], table1.[Action Taken 2]) AS Action_Taken
FROM table1
WHERE table1.[Offence Category] = 'Speeding'
  AND (
        (table1.[Date Of Offence] BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) 
                                      AND DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
        )
        OR 
        (table1.[Date Of Offence] BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) 
                                      AND DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
        )
      )
```

Alternatively, with [`NZ()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c):

```
SELECT table1.ID
      , NZ(table1.[Date Of Offence], table1.[Date Of Offence 2]) AS Date_of_Offence,
      , NZ(table1.[Offence Category], table1.[Offence Category 2]) AS Offence_Category,
      , NZ(table1.[Offence Description], table1.[Offence Description 2]) AS Offence_Description,
      , NZ(table1.[Action Taken], table1.[Action Taken 2]) AS Action_Taken
FROM table1
WHERE table1.[Offence Category] = 'Speeding'
  AND (
        (table1.[Date Of Offence] BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) 
                                      AND DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
        )
        OR 
        (table1.[Date Of Offence] BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date())-1, 1) 
                                      AND DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
        )
      )
```